# Unknown root user on Cisco 1921 router

Tags: cisco

Just a moment ago I ran the `who` command on my router and I noticed myself logged in on `vty 1` but another user `root` was on `vty 0`. The `Location` under that user is some location I do not know (someone from klayer.com). But the strange thing is that I do not see any `root` user in the running-config. If I run `show running-config | i username` then I only get the two names that have been configured, me and another guy who has access (this is not him logged in as `root`) but no user named `root`. How can this be?

I am afraid that I have been hacked and if that is the case then I need to know how to disable this account, and if I can't see it in the running-config then I guess it is not possible to disable it or change the password on it by normal means.

Is this perhaps some dummy account?

EDIT:

after running `who` a few times I get this:

```
ROUTER#show users
    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
 132 vty 0     dummy      idle                 00:00:02
                                             104.143.47.64.static.klayer.com
*133 vty 1     xxx        idle                 00:00:00 mydomain

  Interface    User               Mode         Idle     Peer Address

ROUTER#show users
    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
 132 vty 0     ebooks     idle                 00:00:03
                                             104.143.47.64.static.klayer.com
*133 vty 1     xxx        idle                 00:00:00 mydomain

  Interface    User               Mode         Idle     Peer Address

ROUTER#show users
    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
 132 vty 0     ec2        idle                 00:00:02
                                             104.143.47.64.static.klayer.com
*133 vty 1     xxx        idle                 00:00:00 mydomain

  Interface    User               Mode         Idle     Peer Address

ROUTER#show users
    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
 132 vty 0                idle                 00:00:01
                                             104.143.47.64.static.klayer.com
*133 vty 1     xxx        idle                 00:00:00 mydomain
```

Is this just tries to get into my router? I can see the user name changing from dummy to ebooks to ec2 to nothing, just like he is trying to log in.
Does the `show users/who` commands show unsuccessfull tries as vty lines?

Comment: You're just witnessing a brute-force attack on your router. You might want to restrict access to only the internal network.